# Add Stack Overflow as migration path

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration, migration-path-request

The voting-to-close dialog actually allows to only migrate a question on the meta site for Drupal Answers. It should allow to vote to migrate a question to Stack Overflow, for those questions that are more related to PHP, or JavaScript, rather than Drupal itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be very easy for such questions to get lost in the flood at Stack Overflow.

Of course, they can be migrated anywhere by flagging for moderator attention. I am curious whether the moderators on this site feel that migration path happens often enough to be a vote target (versus a flag).

Comment: Out of 24 migrations, 12 are for SO, 5 are for Server Fault, 2 for Asku Ubuntu, and 1 for Database Administrators; the rest are for the meta site. SO has the most migrations. I don't get the "get lost in the flood at Stack Overflow"; if they are questions for Stack Overflow, they should migrated there, independently from that (which then would still be true even for migrations done from a moderator). IMO, considering that SO is a related site with such migrations, it makes sense to add the migration path to SO; if it were for EL&U, it would make sense to require X migrations already done.

Comment: If you look back 6 months the numbers are very different 2 for both SE and SO.

Comment: @googletorp I have already replied about that. If you are saying that is just me to send questions to SO, then it's just you to send questions to SF; neither of those migration paths should be added, then, following your reasoning.

Comment: @kia I am disinclined to send these question to SO, unless they are *awesome* and are not getting any answers at all here.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I imagine that it is also difficult that a question about PHP has not been already asked on SO. I think it is difficult that a question about PHP is not answered on DA, but it is also probable that who asked a PHP question on DA is not asking an awesome question. That is a good point, which also means [meta-tag:status-declined].

Answer (score 2):

We see a lot of content coming from Stack Overflow, because it's more Drupal than programming related. Questions about stuff like Rules and Views.

I can't remember ever sending questions over to Stackoverflow, maybe once in 6 months tops. If we should have a migrate path, Server Fault seems much move obvious since people from time to time ask a question about setting up Drupal on a server. We also see questions about some server config problem with a Drupal site, which isn't related to Drupal, but is a question about setting up Free BSD, linux, Windows or some other type of server.

I've seen a few of those this month, but generally it's quite rare to see questions being migrated away from the site. I don't think we see enough to make it a close reason. In time maybe, but I think it's premature. Especially since questions usually are closed by moderators anyways - not enough high rep users using the close button.

Comment: Half of the already done migrations are for Stack Overflow; Server Fault has just 5 migrations. If a site needs to be added, that should be Stack Overflow.

Comment: @kiamlaluno If you go back 6 months it's 2/2 for SO and SE. The many posts migrated to SO in initial fase of the site is a poor indicator of what is needed.

Comment: I don't think the fact the migrations have been done at the beginning makes a difference. It just says that users who started to use the site were confused about asking questions here, or on another Stack Exchange sites. There are still new users, nowadays.

Comment: @kiamlaluno The migrations stopped roughly when you stopped as a mod. So the numbers (and this post) are really just saying you like to send questions to SO.

Comment: You migrated questions to Stack Overflow too. 100% of the migrations done to Server Fault are done by you; following what you said, I could say you like to send questions to Server Fault. I don't think that takes to any place.

Answer (score 0):

One thing worth noting in this debate, is that migration paths are only needed if the community closes the question and not a moderator.

My feeling is that all questions or very close to all are closed by mods. So this proposal is meaningless if this is true.

Comment: That is the actual situation, and I agree, but we should think for when the situation changes. After all, I am not asking for populating all the available slots, but adding just a migration path.

Comment: @kiamlaluno lets not jump to the gun. If the need ever arise lets take it then. When we see a lot of migrations and a lot of posts closed by non mods, then we can talk about it. This is just my opinion.

Comment: I am not jumping on the gun. The migration path will be added when who adds it thinks it is worth adding it. Feature requests are kept open until they are implemented, or declined; it is not expected that the feature requests should always be implemented, or implemented the day after they are requested.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I think you are 6-12 months premature - that's all

Comment: also a good point. The volume is just currently too low for this to really be needed, isn't it? We can certainly revisit this at a later time, any time..