# Add other StackExchange network sites to off-topic close reason

Tags: feature-request, migration, migration-path-request

I'm not sure if this maybe should be added to [Custom off-Topic reasons for Drupal Anwers](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2477/custom-off-topic-reasons-for-drupal-anwers) instead, but I figured it's a question in it's own right.

As it stands, we can only cast close votes to move a question to the meta site, however quite a lot of questions that are on the wrong site don't belong here - they belong on ServerFault or StackOverflow (for example).

Is it possible to have at (as a suggestion) ServerFault and possibly StackOverflow? Or should we just continue writing custom close messages that say "*This question belongs on xyz.stackexchange.com*"

I just found [Add Stack Overflow as migration path](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/579/add-stack-overflow-as-migration-path) which had been answered previously which addresses StackOverflow, but I'm wondering if it applies for ServerFault also?

---

Example questions which can be migrated to *stackoverflow*:

- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/207416

Comment: SF really doesn't like getting migrations unless they are good questions from professional admins.  I don't think that most of the ones that we would close here as being off-topic would be a good fit there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with MPD, here. Both *Stack Overflow* and *Server Fault* have strict requirements about the questions they accept; I don't think that (generally speaking) the users on *Drupal Answers* have the experience needed to understand when a question is a better suit for one of those sites.

Furthermore, the new off-topic closing reasons, with their sub-reasons, make the migration path less useful. The default off-topic reason we got from Stack Exchange is the one about general programming questions that should be asked on *Stack Overflow*; we could expand that closing reason to add a reference to *Server Fault*.
The difference between the migration path and the new off-topic closing reasons is that with the latter we aren't saying the other sites surely would accept the question we consider off-topic.

Comment: I would like to see a reference to Server Fault in the off-topic reason for questions like [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/141088/cant-install-composer-in-ubuntu-why).  The options I had for flagging were limited, and I didn't flag as a result.